# simply apply gravity again and again

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

my code applying gravity on any body in my world, and i have a ball , that after it falls down by gravity, i need it to come up again and fall by gravity again.
so it falls down , BUT when i put it back up , it wont fall down again. WHY ??

I call this every frame ::

```
-(void)thick:(ccTime) dt
{


    world->Step(dt,10,10);
    for(b2Body *b=world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) 
    {
        if(b->GetUserData() !=NULL )
           {
               CCSprite *bondanind1=(CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();
               bondanind1.position=ccp( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO  ) ;
               //bondanind.rotation=-1*CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
           }

    }

    if(bondanind.position.y<0 )
    bondanind.position=ccp(300,300);


}
```

so the ball comes up and stay there .
doesnt the gravity works on any body, all time, every frame ????

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious. You should change the position of the body in your condition, not of sprite. And change the condition too look like this:

```
if (body->GetPosition().y < 0)
{
    b2Vec2 newPos(...); //put your pos
    body->SetTransform(newPos, body->GetAngle());
}
```

Now your body just continues falling after it's y position value is less then zero.

Comment: thanks but i did what you have said and when the body get out of screen it doesnt go back to where i put it , i do it like this  : b2Vec2 newPos(200,200); //put your pos

Comment: ok , its working i forgot the add the PTM_RATIO , but it seems that every time the body goes back to world, its gravity is becomes more and more higher, as it add it to the last one . whats wrong here ?

Comment: @Rant: has the problem still remain ?

Comment: yes ..i cant understand why is the ball increasing its speed every time it gets its new position... ??

Comment: @Rant: because you are reseting only position. Reset the velocity too. Use SetLinearVelocity function